# Dropdown Laravel

Tags: laravel, dropdown

Как оформить такой dropdown

```
           <select name="user_id" id="user_id" class="form-control">
             <option value="false">Выберите автора</option>
               @if (isset($users))
                  @foreach($users as $user)
                    <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->name }}</option>
                  @endforeach
               @endif
           </select>
```

через `Form::select()`?
Мой вариант:

```
Form::select('user', [***тут должен быть foreach?***]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

view:

```
{{ Form::select('user_id', $users) }}
```

controller:

```
$users = User::lists('name', 'id');
```

Answer (score 0):

`{!! Form::select('field_name', $array, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}`

`field_name` - будет имя select'a
`$array` - данные для select'a
`null(или id_element'a)` - Если задать id то при формировании селекта выберется нужное значение
`['class' => 'form-control']` - массив со свойствами

Пример функции формирования массива данных для select'a:

```
public function getData()
{
    $data = ModelExample::pluck('name', 'id');
    return $data;
}
```